# multiple search

Tags: search

My question could seem obvious but I don't find the solution.

How to make a search on two fields, like:

```
craft.entries.section('pages').search('foo:bar foo2:bar2')
```

I tried

```
search('foo:bar', 'foo2:bar4')
search('foo:bar and foo2:bar2')
```

none of these seem to work

Answer (score 6):

Your search syntax of `craft.entries.section('pages').search('foo:bar foo2:bar2')` should work and is the equivalent of saying "give me all of the entries in the `pages` section where the field `foo` is equal to `bar` **and** the field `foo2` is equal to `bar2`.

Something that trips people up often is that Craft doesn't do fuzzy searching by default. So `foo:bar` will match *exactly* `bar`, but it will not match `bars`.  You'd need to use `foo:bar*` for that.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm wrong somewhere else then. My search uses a lightswitch and a position:

craft.entries.section('pages').search('onHomePage::true position::"left"')

I get the pages who are not "onHomePage" as well

Comment: And it appears for OR searches this works: search('foo:bar OR foo2:bar2')

Comment: Just to clarify, as foo and bar are petpeeves of mine that I find ... less than helpful; the syntax is .search('fieldHandle:textToFind otherFieldHandle:someOtherText')